# Android - How can I access nested objects?

Tags: json, serialization, gson

I know this question has been brought up quite often, but so far I didn't really find an answer...

I am trying to use Android with GSON. I want to use a JSON String to fill a Gridview but I dont know how to access the nested objects.

The JSON File:

```
[{'ProductCategories':[
{
    'name':'Cat1', 'Product Series':[
        {
            'name':'ProdSeries1', 'Description':'Lorem Ipsum Bla Bla','Products':[
                {
                    'name':'Product1','key':'value','key':'...'
                },
                {
                    'name':'Product2','key':'value','key':'...'
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
},
]
}]
```

I made 4 classes:`Products`,`ProductSeries`,`ProductCatalog` and `ProductCategory`.

example:

```
public class ProductCatalog {

@SerializedName("ProductCategories")
@Expose
private List<ProductCategory> productCategories = null;

public List<ProductCategory> getProductCategories() {
    return productCategories;
}

public void setProductCategories(List<ProductCategory> productCategories) {
    this.productCategories = productCategories;
}
```

}

After that I parsed the JSON with gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<ProductCatalog>>(){}.getType();
List<ProductCatalog> productcatalog = gson.fromJson(JSONstring,type);
```

Now I have a parsed list of the JSON data but dont know how to work with the nested objects like 'Product1'. I thought the getters would help, but I cant access `getProductCategories()` in my activity. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using Gson means This will help you

```
public class MainClazz {
@SerializedName("ProductCategories")
@Expose
private List<ProductCategory> productCategories = null;
public List<ProductCategory> getProductCategories() {
 return productCategories;
}
public void setProductCategories(List<ProductCategory> productCategories) {
 this.productCategories = productCategories;
}
}

public class Product {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("key")
@Expose
private String key;

public String getName() {
  return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
   this.name = name;
}

public String getKey() {
  return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
  this.key = key;
}

}


public class ProductCategory {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("Product Series")
@Expose
private List<ProductSeries> productSeries = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public List<ProductSeries> getProductSeries() {
return productSeries;
}

public void setProductSeries(List<ProductSeries> productSeries) {
this.productSeries = productSeries;
}

}



public class ProductSeries {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("Description")
@Expose
private String description;
@SerializedName("Products")
@Expose
private List<Product> products = null;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public List<Product> getProducts() {
return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
this.products = products;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But my classes look exact the same... After `List<ProductCatalog> productcatalog = gson.fromJson(JSONstring,type);` I can not use the getter `productcatalog.getProductCategories()`

Comment: You have replaced main class(`MainClazz `) name with `ProductCatalog` and still your not getting

Comment: post your full json

Comment: Well I tried a bit and now I am able to use the getters and setters. Problem was that I had a list and first needed to select an object with`.get(0)` or `.iterator()`... Now I can use the JSON data properly.